# Updating table value complex operation

Tags: sql

I have a table which has 2 columns A & B, and a set of keywords. Basically i have to compare each Keyword with Column A and if there is a match, i have to update that Column B to 'Y'. Here the Keyword matching with the Column A must NOT start or end with an alphabet.

Comment: can u add an example?

Comment: Keyword- OK, Fine, Bye
Column A- OKO, Fine, Byeee.....

Now i compare keyword and Column A , so only Fine should be a positive result (coz Column A must not start or end with an alphabet)....

Column B for FINE must be updated to 'YES'

Comment: @umzee please add a proper understandable example.

Comment: [Here's a good place to start](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).

Comment: You said **coz Column A must not start or end with an alphabet** but "Fine" starts and ends with an alphabet!

Answer (score 0):

Though I didnt quite totally understand your question, with whatever I could understand I guess this should work. (Oracle Syntax)

```
update table t1 set columnB = case when keyword = columnA and regexp_like(ColumnA,'^\d.*\d$') then 'Yes' else 'No' end;
```